# How could I use HTML snippets in VS Community 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-snippets

How could I easly generate next code in Visual Studio Community 2017 in an ASP.NET MVC project?

```html
<h1 id="welcome"></h1>
<div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-4">
        <h2><h2>
        <p></p>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4">
        <h2><h2>
        <p></p>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4">
        <h2><h2>
        <p></p>
    </section>
</div>
```

using next snippet

```
h1#welcome+div.row>(section.col-md-4>(h2+p))*3
```

Like on this image

[image]

This must work inside a `.cshtml` *(HTML with razor code)* and `.html` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> h1#welcome+div.row>(section.col-md-4>(h2+p))*3
> ```

Looks like you are doing [Zen Coding](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/zen-coding-a-new-way-to-write-html-code/) of HTML. VS needs an extension for that to work.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ZenCoding